# How to precisely replace the string

Tags: php

```
$string = 'I am chan, my son is chan_junior';
$search = array('chan', 'chan_junior');
$replace = array('a', 'b');
$new = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
echo $new;
```

I want to replace the string to `I am a, my son is b`, but the result is `I am a, my son is a_junior`.  Is there a function to make it happen?

Comment: if you don't want to use pattern, you can simply reorder $search = array( 'chan_junior', 'chan');

Answer (score 0):

That happens because php search first for "chan", replace it on 2 places and then don't find second string. Search for longer strings first.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$string = 'I am chan, my son is chan_junior';
$search = array('chan', 'chan_junior');
$replace = array('a', 'b');
$str_arr = explode(' ', $string);
$count = count($str_arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++)
{
    $word = preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z0-9\-]*|[^A-Za-z0-9\-]*$/', '', $str_arr[$i]);
    if (in_array($word, $search))
    {
        $key = array_search($word, $search);
        $str_arr[$i] = str_replace($word, $replace[$key], $str_arr[$i]);
    }
}
$new = implode(' ', $str_arr);
echo $new;
```